# home directory after ssh

Tags: python, ssh, flask, web-deployment

I'm developing a web app on from a server/cluster at my university, which has all my code, that I want to run on the back end.

I will post my general question first, and then the detailed code and error messages that I get. My main question is, when I'm usually developing locally on my computer any web app using python and a microframework or framework like flask or django respectively, the address on my browser that I go to, to make sure everything is running is: http://0.0.0.0:5000, or something around localhost. However, when I've ssh'ed to the server/cluster, what would my new address be? Suppose I ssh to user@cluster1.uni.ece.edu. Should I be able to see the output of my website by going to http://cluster1.uni.ece.edu ?

Detailed specs:

The code I'm running is supposed to let anyone upload an image from the client side to the server from a web browser.

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename

# Initialize the Flask application

app = Flask(__name__)

# This will be th path to the upload directory
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads/'

# These are the extension that we are accepting to be uploaded
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['png','jpg','jpeg'])

# For a given file, return whether it's an allowed type or not
def allowed_file(file_name):
  return '.' in filename and \
    filename.rsplit('.',1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

# This route will show a form to perform an AJAX request
# jQuery is loaded to execute the request and update the 
# value of the operation

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

#Route that will process the file upload
@app.route('/upload',methods=['POST'])
def upload():
  #Get the name of the uploaded file
  file = request.files['file']
  #Check if the file is one of the allowed types/extensions
  if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    #Make the filename safe, remove unsupported chars
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    #Move the file from the temporal folder to
    #the upload folder we setup
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
    #Redirect the user to the uplaoded_file route, which
    #will basically show on the browser the uploaded file
    return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))


# This route is expecting a parameter containing the name of a file.
# Then it will locate that file on the upload directory and show it on the
# browser, so if the user uploads an image, that image is going to be shown
# after the upload.

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
  return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(
    host='0.0.0.0',
    port=int("80"),
    debug=True
  )
```

The code above was borrowed from another website on a tutorial. Anyhow, the error that I get is this one:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Demo1.py", line 60, in <module>
    debug=True
  File "/home/arturo/miniconda/envs/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/arturo/miniconda/envs/venv1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 618, in run_simple
    test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/home/arturo/miniconda/envs/venv1/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

A friend of mine is developing a similar site and somehow's he's managed to get it working on: http://cluster1.uni.ece.edu:8000/Demo1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer of your first question is yes. If you run the web application in your server you will be able to see the output of the website. By default the app will run on port 5000.

For the second issue, Check this answer of the question: [socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709886/1113211). You have changed the port of the development server to 80 without being a root user. Run your application like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(
    host='0.0.0.0',
    debug=True
  )
```

You will be able to see the output in http://cluster1.uni.ece.edu:5000.
If you want to run it on 80 port you have to have the root access.
I will recommend you to use a production server like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) if you want to deploy it.